# How to search for a whole word with special char using oracle contains?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column short_desc in my table that is context indexed.

When i search like below

```
select * from table1 where CONTAINS (short_desc,'{product\_id}') > 0
```

I get results like

> abc product_id
>
> abc product id

The escaped character behaves like an OR and the query searches for 'product_id' or 'product id'

How can i search for the whole word 'product_id' only?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try select * from table1 where short_desc like '%product_id%'

Comment: I want to use contains.

Comment: Like works...but Contains take 300 msec. Like takes 14 secs. So i want to use contains

Comment: Could you do both?  The `contains` to use the index, and the `like` to narrow down the results.

Comment: This is a legacy application. I really cant change much in it. I am just curious why it is not working and changing the search word in particular manner (like escaping the character properly etc) will fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

According to [Oracle*Text documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqspcl.htm#i1006222) non-alphabetic characters are treated as whitespace (so product$id and product_id both treated as 'product id').

This behavior demonstrated at [this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4355/2). Don't matter which non-aplhanumeric symbol placed between 'product' and 'id'.

To alter that you must [define underscore as `printjoin`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/ind.htm#i1007050) in lexer used by CONTEXT index.

I can't demonstrate this in SQLFiddle because access to `ctx_ddl` package restricted here, but this code must do the job:

```
create table table1(short_desc varchar2(200))
/

-- Add lexer definition and set '_' as "printjoin"
begin
  ctx_ddl.create_preference('mylex', 'BASIC_LEXER');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mylex', 'printjoins', '_');
end;
/

-- Specify new lexer definition while creating index
create index table1_ctx_index on table12(short_desc) 
  indextype is ctxsys.context 
  parameters ( 'LEXER mylex' )
/

insert into table1(short_desc) values('1 product id 2')
/
insert into table1(short_desc) values('3 product_id 4')
/
insert into table1(short_desc) values('5 product#id 6')
/
insert into table1(short_desc) values('7 productXid 8')
/
insert into table1(short_desc) values('9 product-id 10')
/

alter index table1_ctx_index rebuild
/
```

Answer (score 0):

can try this

```
 select * from table1 where CONTAINS (short_desc,'{product'||'\_id}') > 0
```

Comment: It gives the same result.

Comment: try using REGEXP_LIKE ...I think it will work...i dont have sql with me right now else would have provided you exact query

Comment: Would not that be much slower?